# SSRS 2008 r2 column group writing mode does not work on CRM

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report column group which I set WritingMode property to "**Rotate 270**" as I need the text presented vertically. It works like a charm when previewing on visual studio or when exported to excel/pdf but when I execute the report on CRM, theese columns are shown like mirrored(opposite direction).
I've googled it and found some old posts saying it's a known SSRS bug but I coudn't find anything more recent. Do you guys know any way to fix it?

**That's the way it's shown on crm**

[image: 1]

**That's the correct way/how it gets when exported/visualized from VS**

[image: 2]

Comment: Curious what it does when you change the WritingMode to "Vertical"?

Comment: It goes horizontal on CRM, so weird.

Comment: Hmmm... [this link](http://sqljason.com/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html) could be useful?  The author uses custom code to do the same.  Not sure if it'll work in your case, but worth a look.

Comment: I've come across that link a few times but I'm trying to avoid those codes, it was posted like 8y ago, it has to be an easier solution :(
Anyways, I've just changed some properties like CanGrowth, CanShrink, VerticalAlign, TextAlign and Direction and now the columns look a bit nicer, still different on CRM but the key user accepeted this way. haha thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to reproduce this event, but I am unable to, see attached image.

[image]

Comment: I noticed it happens just when I rotate a column group, I got another columns with fixed texts and it works fine.